# I am trying to run docker on my port and i got this error below, How can I solve it?

Tags: doc, docker-build

Dockerfile

FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build"]

EXPOSE 1234

**docker run -d -p 1234:1234 -my-portfolio-app and I got the below error.**

Error: Unable to deserialize cloned data due to invalid or unsupported version.
at deserialize (v8.js:343:7)
at deserialize (/app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/serializer.js:249:48)
at loadRequestGraph (/app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/RequestTracker.js:854:52)
at async Function.init (/app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/RequestTracker.js:821:17)
at async Parcel._init (/app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:256:28)
at async Parcel.watch (/app/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:315:7)
at async run (/app/node_modules/parcel/lib/cli.js:351:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! educator-js-codespace-template@1.0.0 start: `parcel`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the educator-js-codespace-template@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-20T06_49_18_593Z-debug.log